# How to install ubuntu alongside installed windows 8.1?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi, bios

I am trying to dual boot windows 8.1 and ubuntu, but i don't know exactly how to do it, since i tried it once and it went really wrong. Now, as i said, i have windows 8.1 installed, and in system information, it appears "BIOS mode: legacy". However, i don't know if i need to install ubuntu in uefi mode or legacy mode. I already have Ubuntu on a usb stick ready to boot. I really am not very experienced in this kind of things. Can you help me? I really need ubuntu for university, but i also need windows. Thank you :)

Comment: You need to install Ubuntu in the same boot mode UEFI or BIOS as your Windows is installed. Post this: `sudo parted -l` as Windows only boots from MBR(msdos) with BIOS and only from gpt with UEFI. But if you used Windows to install in BIOS mode to a gpt drive, it does not convert correctly and the Ubuntu installer will not work. If that is the case you can use fixparts, but we need to see what existing partitions are first.

Answer (score 0):

This is link have a people quesion problems same you. [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

You can find answer for you